# ruby chunk_while in windows not working

Tags: ruby, windows

I am using RubyInstaller distribution of Ruby 2.2.1  on windows. I am running the following code.

```
a = [0, 9, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7, 5, 9, 5]
p a.chunk_while {|i, j| i <= j }.to_a
```

This code is giving the following error:-

```
undefined method `chunk_while'
```

I have figured out that chunk_while is only for ruby 2.3.0. I think there is no RubyInstaller distribution of Ruby 2.3.0. Is there any way to run this method on windows machine?

Comment: Ruby-core team member [Marc-André Lafortune](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/users/182) maintains and develops the [`backports`](https://rubygems.org/gems/backports) gem, which tries to make as much new functionality as can be reasonably implemented in pure Ruby available in oder versions. Usually, if you want to use newer functionality in older versions of Ruby, you can find it there, provided it can actually be implemented in pure Ruby. (New syntax like the JSON-style `Hash` literals or `->` stabby lambda, or new language semantics like Refinements and `prepend` obviously *cannot* be provided.)

Comment: So, *if* there is an implementation of [`Enumerable#chunk_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while), then you will find it there. Unfortunately, at least as of now, `backports` only tracks features up to Ruby 2.1.0. Should it ever be added, it would be available via 

    `require 'backports/2.3.0/enumerable/chunk_while'`

Answer (score 1):

Just use its counterpart [`Enumerable#slice_when`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) until RubyInstaller is updated (or if there are other reasons 2.3-only features can't be used):

```
a.slice_when {|i, j| !(i <= j) }.to_a  # => [[0, 9], [2, 2, 3], [2, 7], [5, 9], [5]]
# or simply
a.slice_when {|i, j| i > j }.to_a      # => [[0, 9], [2, 2, 3], [2, 7], [5, 9], [5]]
```

Here's also a possible implementation:

```
module Enumerable
  def chunk_while(&block)
    block || raise(ArgumentError, 'no block given')
    slice_when { |before, after| !block.call(before, after) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey :) i think you already gooled it right ? Found the website too and a few other ones ... It seems that 2.2.3 is the latest version, maybe you should try that version

http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/